# Python opening each the unread emails

Tags: python, email, selenium, webdriver, gmail

Could you please suggest how to handle the opening process of each unread mail ?

Now it works this way:

1. Login to Gmail
2. Open inbox
3. Click on the unread mail
4. Back to inbox
5. Open next unread mail

But I noted that the selenium open not each mail. The selenium opens through one mail. I tried to use index -= 1 but it doesn't work.

There is code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.color import Color

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://gmail.com')
assert 'Gmail' in driver.title

try:
    login = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='identifierId']")))
finally:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']").send_keys("********@gmail.com" + Keys.RETURN)
try:
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")))
finally:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input").send_keys(
    "PASSWORD" + Keys.RETURN)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
unread_mails = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='zF']")
for index, mails in enumerate(unread_mails):
    print(unread_mails[index])
    if unread_mails[index].is_displayed():
        wait.until_not(EC.staleness_of(unread_mails[index]))
        try:
           unread_mails[index].click()
           index -= 2
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
           pass
     driver.get('https://mail.google.com')
     try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                   'confirmation popup to appear.')
        confirmation_alert = driver.switch_to.alert
        confirmation_alert.accept()
     except TimeoutException:
        print('no alerts')
unread_mails = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='zF']")
```

Comment: Please check how many elements are returned by the xpath //*[@class='zF']. It may be only one. Also, Gmail has dynamic class name. So you can't use it to find unread mail.

Comment: Thanks. I checked count of elements it looks good. It seems that it's not dynamic class name. The selenium goes through all elements but it doesn't go through each mail. It skips one mail each time.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just use the gmail API? It would be more straightforward.

Comment: May be because you are decrementing the index value by 2 in the line index -= 2

Comment: @JeffC I can't use the gmail API because I need to open each email and click on specific link there then 'do something' and back to next mail again.  The gmail API could figure out this issue but idea is full automation. However I'll think about Gmail API again. It might be easier to solve it. Thanks

Comment: @Murthi I used decrementing for solving an issue with the skipping index.

Comment: Maybe you can use the gmail API to open all the unread emails, get the specific link and store them in an array. Once all the links are collected, loop through the array navigating to each URL and 'do something'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using selenium or scrapping to solve this issue is not the best choice for some reasons.

1. Google have dynamic load of the HTML and it can cause you a lot of problems.
2. You may come across with the reCaptcha service (Im not robot) then what?
3. This illegal operation by google rules and you may be blocked.

Therefore I'm truly recommend you to use Google API to solve this issue.